# How old iPad apps work on iOS 11 on split view

Tags: ios, ipad, ios11, splitview

As we know that yesterday was the release of officially iOS 11, and this include multiple features including multitasking (Split View, side over and Picture in Picture). And this [guideline for multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/system-capabilities/multitasking/) gives overview of multitasking.

I've uploaded multiples app so I'm curious to know that what will happen to old apps which we uploaded, will Apple handles those or we need to upload newer version of those to support Multitasking split view (I don't have iPad but will get soon) ?

Comment: Split View, Slide Over and Picture in Picture was already present in iOS 10 and active on all supported iPads (iPad Air+ and iPad Pro)...

Comment: You can use split view in the Xcode 9 iPad simulator.

Comment: @iCyberPaul not if you have library dependencies that are not built for x86-64 simulator.